# Bulk insertion in django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, bulkinsert

When I am trying to create multiple instances in a single request it shows error if one instance is not correct in the batch. But how can I write my create method to insert correct instances in the batch. That means only correct instances will insert in the db and also show the errors message for the wrong instances.

```
[
    {
        "name": "oil",
        "unit_price": 200
    },
    {
        "name": "meat",
        "unit_type": "raw",
        "unit_price": 1000
    }
        "name": "salt",
        "unit_type": "raw",
        "unit_price": -100
    }

]
```

I want to insert first two instances will be insert in the db and for last one it will throws an error like this.

```
    "errors":
 [

        {
            "unit_price": [
                "Enter positive number."
            ]
        }
 ]
```

Here is my serializer

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_unit_price(self, value):
         if (value) > 0:
             return value
         raise serializers.ValidationError("Enter positive number.")

    class Meta:
        model  = Product
        fields = [ 'name', 'unit_type', 'unit_price']
```

Also my views function is

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def store(request):

    serializer          =   ProductSerializer(data = request.data,many=True)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response({'response_code': '500', 'response': status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'message': 'Something went wrong', 'data': request.data, 'errors': serializer.errors})
```

Comment: Are you aware of library [djangorestframework-bulk](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-bulk/)?

Comment: @RossRogers Last release April 2015?

Comment: I'm still using it and it works great.  Old code doesn't mean bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using one `ProductSerializer` instance, you won't be able to save if `is_valid` returns `False`. If you want to create all valid datasets and return the ones that errored, you might want to consider creating a serializer instance per entry, and keeping track of the data returned. You can build out a list of response values for the user that way, so partial failure is allowed.

My suggestion will not make this a "bulk" operation, but it technically isn't with `many=True`. `many=True` just wraps your serializer with a `ListSerializer`, which just calls `create` using the wrapped serializer per attribute. So you're performing a `save()` per instance of data as is.

Comment: Many init gets called when `many=True`: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d985c7cbb999b2bc18a109249c583e91f4c27aec/rest_framework/serializers.py#L124-L154

This calls the list serializer class (defaults to `ListSerializer`) with the current serializer as the child. This `ListSerializer` on `save()` will call `create()`, which calls `create()` on the child per arg instance: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d985c7cbb999b2bc18a109249c583e91f4c27aec/rest_framework/serializers.py#L678-L713

Comment: As for not allowing save if `is_valid()` is false, that's true on both single serializer instances and list serializers: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d985c7cbb999b2bc18a109249c583e91f4c27aec/rest_framework/serializers.py#L168-L175

Comment: How can i use that in my code? I can't  understand the implementation.